# Где проверить пунктуацию у Тютчева? про Элизиум теней?

Tags: пунктуация

> Душа моя, Элизиум теней,
>
> Теней безмолвных, светлых и прекрасных,
>
> Ни помыслам годины буйной сей,
>
> Ни радостям, ни горю не причастных!
>
> ---
>
> Душа моя, Элизиум теней,
>
> Что общего меж жизнью и тобою!
>
> Меж вами, призраки минувших лучших дней,
>
> И сей бесчувственной толпою?..

**[источник](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_(%D0%A2%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2)/%D0%9F%D0%A1%D0%A1_2002_(%D0%A1%D0%9E))**

Как говорится, две большие разницы...

> Душа моя, Элизиум теней,
>
> Теней безмолвных, светлых и прекрасных,
>
> Ни помыслам годины буйной сей,
>
> Ни радостям, ни горю не причастных,—
>
> Душа моя, Элизиум теней,
>
> Что общего меж жизнью и тобою!
>
> Меж вами, призраки минувших, лучших дней,
>
> И сей бесчувственной толпою?..

**[источник](http://www.world-art.ru/lyric/lyric.php?id=2325)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И - восьмистишие или две строфы?

---

ПОСТСКРИПТУМ.

[Другие редакции и варианты](https://ostihe.ru/analiz-stihotvoreniya/tyutcheva/dusha-moya-elizium-tenej)

> В автографе в 1-й и 5-й строках после слов «Душа моя» стоит запятая, в
>   конце второй строки — запятая, в конце 4-й и 6-й — восклицательный
>   знак, 7-й — запятая, в конце стихотворения — вопросительный знак и
>   многоточие. Строфы отделены интервалом, но без отчеркивания. В конце
>   стихотворения — длинная линия, отделившая его от следующего — («из
>   Гейне») «В которую из двух влюбиться…». Слово «Элизиум» написано с
>   прописной буквы, также и некоторые другие существительные и
>   местоимения — «Горю», «Вами», «Призраки». Третья строка — «Ни помыслам
>   годины буйной сей»; в конце 1, 3, 5-й отсутствуют какие-либо знаки;
>   думается, что поэт не завершил синтаксическое оформление. На обороте —
>   «Я помню время золотое…», на следующем листе — «На древе
>   человечества…», «Как дочь родную на закланье…».
>
> Датируется 1830-ми гг.; было послано Тютчевым И.С. Гагарину в начале
>   мая 1836 г.
>
> Во всех указанных изданиях 3-я строка — «Ни замыслам годины буйной
>   сей». Синтаксическая структура первой строфы издателями осознается
>   по-разному: 1-я строчка понята как главное предложение, в котором
>   подлежащее и сказуемое отделены тире («Душа моя— элизиум теней») — в
>   Совр. 1836 г. и 1854 г. в Изд. 1868, Изд. СПб. 1886 ; притом как
>   завершенное предложение, заканчивающееся восклицательным знаком, — в
>   Изд. 1868 (хотя в первом и втором изданиях Биогр. Аксаков здесь
>   поставил запятую) и в Изд. СПб. 1886. Но в первых трех изданиях — вся
>   строфа мыслится как одно предложение, где к главному присоединяется
>   развернутое приложение, и тогда первая строка заканчивается запятой
>   (или запятой и тире, как в Совр. 1854 г.). В Изд. 1900 — «Душа моя,
>   Элизиум теней»; здесь вторая часть фразы оформлена как приложение, а
>   все дальнейшее — причастный оборот к слову «теней».
>
> Первая строка второй строфы оформляется обычно аналогично первой
>   строке стихотворения («Душа моя — Элизиум теней»); так в изданиях
>   1850-х гг. и двух последующих, но в пушкинском Совр. и в Изд. 1900 эта
>   строка фиксирует обращение — «Душа моя, Элизиум теней» и завершается
>   строчка или восклицательным знаком, как в пушкинском Совр. и Изд.
>   1868. или запятой, как в Биогр. и в Изд. 1900. В этом случае предложение заканчивается во второй строке, в конце которой — знак
>   вопроса («Что общего меж жизнью и тобою?»). Но в первых пяти изданиях
>   здесь — запятая. И тогда вторая строфа представляет собой одно сложное
>   предложение, завершающееся вопросительным знаком (в Изд. СПб. 1886
>   здесь знак вопроса и тире), в Совр. 1836 г. — вопросительным знаком с
>   многоточием.
>
> В изданиях XX в. также постоянные колебания в синтаксическом
>   оформлении. В Изд. Маркса 1-я и 5-я строчки оформлены одинаково («Душа
>   моя — элизиум теней»), первая строфа понята как одно предложение, во
>   второй строфе выделены два предложения, включающие по две строки. Г.И.
>   Чулков в Изд. Чулков I отказался от тире в середине 1-й и 5-й строк,
>   но в Изд. Чулков. 1935 (с. 103) в обоих случаях тире восстановлено. В
>   новом издании изменилось понимание в целом второй строфы, которая
>   стала осмысливаться как одно предложение с восклицательным знаком на
>   конце (раньше здесь был знак вопроса и многоточие). В изданиях,
>   подготовленных К.В. Пигаревым, также заметны колебания: в Лирике I 1-я
>   и 5-я строки оформлены по-разному: «Душа моя — Элизиум теней» и «Душа
>   моя, Элизиум теней», но в более позднем Изд. 1984 в обоих случаях
>   здесь стоит запятая между словами «моя» и «Элизиум». Если в раннем
>   издании первая строфа включила в себя одно законченное предложение, то
>   в Изд. 1984 первая строфа завершается запятой и тире, а предложение
>   заканчивается в конце шестой строки. Написание слова «Элизиум» (с
>   прописной или строчной буквы) все время в изданиях варьируется.
>   Думается, целесообразнее всего максимально приблизиться к знакам
>   автографа, позволяющим все первые шесть строк понимать как
>   взволнованное обращение поэта к душе (отсюда два восклицательных
>   знака).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто ж его знает, что верно и как было у автора. У меня в сборнике "Русская поэзия" из "Библиотеки учителя" за 1987 г. второй вариант, но разделено на 2 строфы.

Comment: "Душа моя, Элизиум теней…"

Другие редакции и варианты
Автограф — РГАЛИ. Ф. 505. Оп. 1. Ед. хр. 18. Л. 1 об.

Первая публикация — Совр. 1836. Т. IV. С. 41, под общим названием «Стихотворения, присланные из Германии», под номером XXIII, с подписью «Ф. Т.»...  https://ostihe.ru/analiz-stihotvoreniya/tyutcheva/dusha-moya-elizium-tenej

Comment: Спасибо, Галя, прочитала с удовольствием.